# Can I use relational parameters that query as items on their own?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, relations, ecommerce, query

I am running a craft site on craft 2.6.2997 and latest craft commerce.

I am building a url query that allows the user to add query params to the url with a bit of js. The url structure is as follows as an example:

`?types[]=coffeeAndSide&materials[]=lacquer`

On each click of the tags below it adds/removes the query items to the url and then I use an ajax GET request to pull the data from the page url to show the results.

One piece of trouble I am having is that in the url above the results should technically show something because there are relations in the `coffeeAndSide` types query and it should show regardless of materials having this item in it. My query setup is below:

```
{% set typesQuery = craft.request.getParam('types') %}
{% set materialQuery = craft.request.getParam('materials') %}

{# Start an array of search parameters (relationParam) with 'and' to match ALL categories #}
{% set relationParam = ['or','and'] %}
{% set productTypes = [] %}
{% set allValues = [] %}

{# Find categories that match the slugs in your query string... #}
{% for querySlug in materialQuery %}
  {% set materialCategory = craft.categories.group('materials').slug(querySlug) %}

  {# And merge them into the relationParam array. #}
  {% set relationParam = relationParam|merge({targetElement: materialCategory}) %}
  {% set allValues = allValues|merge({targetElement: materialCategory}) %}
{% endfor %}


{% for queryTypeSlug in typesQuery %}

    {% set type = queryTypeSlug %}

    {% set productTypes = productTypes|merge([type]) %}
    {% set allValues = allValues|merge([type]) %}

{% endfor %}

{% if relationParam|length < 1 %}
  {% set relationParam = '' %}
{% endif %}

{% set products = craft.commerce.products({
  type: productTypes
}).relatedTo(relationParam) %}


{% set queriedProducts = products.find() %}
```

For some reason it doesn't show anything when really it should.

Is there a way I can get it to work where both `types` and `materials` can query on their own and if either of them have a result that should technically show?

Thanks,
Mark